# Baking normal map produces strange result

Tags: baking, normal-map

I am following the [Anvil tutorial](https://youtu.be/0r-cGjVKvGw?list=PLcpbyAte3x6Y0skyLUZEUKOlqcsFmPpHT&t=550) and all was well until the normal baking step. The result I get from blender is different than the tutorial, I tried reiterating on steps, but I got the same wrong results. I am not sure what I missed.
Both objects were set to smooth shading, object face normals look right to me

**My baked normal output**[image: my baked normal output]

**My scene setup**[image: my scene setup]

Comment: Could you upload your UV Unwrap?

Comment: @joshsanfelici you're right, there was a problem with the UV Unwrap, is was scaled up too much. Thank you!